# How to get a random image when we reload the HTML browser ? using javascript, css and html

Tags: javascript, html, image, random, getelementbyid

I've checked answers on this topic and I tried a bunch of them but still doesn't work for me. I would like that a different image appears when I reload my HTML page.

For now, I have this code that is quite simple :

HTML :

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/index.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img id="image_shower_vehicule" class="vehicule" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS :

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:0;
}

.vehicule {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

JS :

```
var images_array_vehicule = ['vehicule1.png','vehicule2.png','vehicule3.png'];

function getRandomImagevehicule() {

random_index_vehicule = Math.floor(Math.random() * images_array_vehicule.length);
selected_image_vehicule = images_array_vehicule[random_index_vehicule];
document.getElementById('image_shower_vehicule').src =`../public/layers/vehicule/${selected_image_vehicule}`;

}
```

I have the following folders directory...: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtnML.png

Any ideas that could help me ?

The future step is to do the same thing with different layers and overlay the chosen images with z-index but for now I just want to have a random image when I reload the page.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried looking in your developer console for any errors? I would start there. Also, you aren't calling the function anywhere. Have you tried adding `getRandomImagevehicule();` after you define the function? If you look at this fiddle, your code works. https://jsfiddle.net/87rxzn4e/

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo, since the function was not called and adding that will solve the question.

Comment: To @disinfor, sorry I didn't see your comment at first look.I change the path to 
document.getElementById('image_shower_vehicule').src = `./layers/vehicule/${selected_image_vehicule}`;
and it works.... 

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP.
We can close the topic. :)

Comment: You can delete the question. You don't have to wait until it gets closed. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

call fuction onload :

```
<body onload="getRandomImagevehicule()">.... </body>
```

js code :

```js
var images_array_vehicule = ['vehicule1.png','vehicule2.png','vehicule3.png'];
        function getRandomImagevehicule()
        {
          random_index_vehicule = Math.floor(Math.random() * images_array_vehicule.length);
          selected_image_vehicule = images_array_vehicule[random_index_vehicule];
          document.getElementById('image_shower_vehicule').src =`../public/layers/vehicule/${selected_image_vehicule}`;
        }
```

```css
 #container
 {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:0;
}
.vehicule {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body onload="getRandomImagevehicule()">
  <div id="container">
    <img id="image_shower_vehicule" class="vehicule" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What did you change? You need to add information about what you did, not just "Try This". (Also, there is no reason to put the function `onload`. You can just add it to the javascript file)

Comment: call function onload `<body onload="getRandomImagevehicule()">`

Comment: I know what you changed. You need to add that to the question so OP knows.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Unfortunately, this is still not showing anything... 
Is there a possibility that the path I used in the js code is not well defined ? I don't how if there is an easy way to check...

Comment: sorry i don't understand in english